# ¿Como puedes verficar que un parametro existe dentro de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, mysqlprocedure

Necesito que un procedure muestre un mensaje u otro en función de si la información como parámetro que le pases existe o no dentro de la tabla.

Código:

```sql
DELIMITER &&
CREATE PROCEDURE ejer2 (IN autor varchar(30), OUT mensaje varchar(30)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE control INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT
    count(*)
INTO
    control
FROM
    escritor
WHERE
    autor = Autor;
    IF (control != 0 ) THEN
            SET
    mensaje = "nombre y apellidos del autor nace en lugar de nacimiento el fecha de nacimiento";
    ELSE 
            SET
    mensaje = "No existe";
END IF;
END; &&
DELIMITER ;
```

De este modo funciona el procedimiento pero independientemente de lo que introduzcas se muestra el primer mensaje.

Comment: autor siempre va a ser igual a Autor.. las consultas son case insensitive...ç

Comment: Además de llamar igual al parámetro de la función (autor) en el mensaje de respuesta haces referencia al lugar y fecha de nacimiento y no los tienes en cuenta en la consulta ni los pides como parámetros.

Comment: No deberías hacerlo así, puede ser mas conveniente usar [*Señales*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Me parece extraño que tu procedimiento funcione, debido a que as definido una variable OUT `mensaje` VARCHAR(30) y tu cadena dentro del procedimiento tiene mucho mas que eso.
y al ejecutarlo me indica el siguiente mensaje:

> SQL Error [1406] [22001]: Data truncation: Data too long for column
> 'mensaje' at row 1

Lo que indican los colegas también hay que considerarlo tanto por el tema técnico como para no confundirse cuando se hace la revisión del procedimiento.

modifique tu procedimiento quedando de la siguiente manera:

```sql
DELIMITER &&
CREATE PROCEDURE ejer2 (IN in_autor varchar(30), OUT mensaje varchar(30)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE control INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT
    count(*)
INTO
    control
FROM
    escritor
WHERE
    in_autor = Autor;
    IF (control != 0 ) THEN
            SET
    mensaje = "nombre y apellidos del autor n";
    ELSE 
            SET
    mensaje = "No existe";
END IF;
END; &&
DELIMITER ;
```

Probado y funcionando , tal ves tu problema se genera cuando haces el llamado al procedimiento este procedimiento así tal cual como esta creado no entrega un mensaje, lo que hace es setear una variable de salida `mensaje` la cual se debe invocar desde el gestor de base de datos.

Para hace el llamado al procedimiento:

```
CALL ejer2 ('nombre_del_autor',@mensaje);
```

y para invocar la variable seteada

```
SELECT @mensaje;
```